# Build a list of criterias of optional filters for retrieving records nhibernate c#

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, fluent-nhibernate, criteria, nhibernate-criteria

I have a table with many records in it which can be filtered by rowstatus, created date, modifieddate.

I am using fluent nhibernate as the ORM.

Now the request that can come in the WebAPi can be:

?rowstatus=0
OR
?rowstatus=0&createddate=05-30-2013
OR
createddate=05-30-2013
OR
modifieddate=05-29-2013&rowsstatus=0

as you can see any combination of filters can come in into the query string.

I wanted to know, how can I dynamically build a list of criteria and give it to my ISession object to execute. what is the best way to do it.

Currently I have so many overloaded functions to do it and it is ugly. Here is an example of what I am using. I want to inject dynamically rowstatus and createddate.

```
_session.QueryOver<ApiData>()
                           .Where(a => (a.status== rowstatus)
                                       && (a.createdDate== createddate)).List().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I finally did it:

```
        var status = queryParams.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Key == "status").Value;
        var entity = queryParams.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Key == "entity").Value;
        var start = queryParams.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Key == "start").Value;

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(status))
        {
            query.Where(r => r.RowStatus == Convert.ToInt32(status));
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(entity))
        {
            query.Where(r => r.EntityType == entity);
        }

        //Ensure that this should be the last filter criteria to be applied
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(start))
        {
            query.Skip(Convert.ToInt32(start));
        }

        var count = query.RowCount();

        var results = query.Take(apiUser.ApiLimit).List().Select(c => _cryptography.Decrypt(c.Json)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I use `nHibernate Criteria` queries for this type of scenario as they are extremely flexible and you can build them up as you go depending on the search parameters that are supplied.

I have created a basic example for you below based on some of the criteria you specified in your question, you should be able to modify my example to suit your specific needs.

```
public IList<ApiData> SearchApiData(int? rowStatus, DateTime? createdDate)
{

        ICriteria query = _session.CreateCriteria<ApiData>();

        if (rowStatus.HasValue)
        {
            query.Add(Restrictions.Eq("RowStatus", rowStatus.Value));
        }

        if (createdDate.HasValue)
        {
            query.Add(Restrictions.Eq("CreatedDate", createdDate.Value));
        }

        return query.List<ApiData>();

}
```

Also when I have many search parameters I normally create a class structure to enable me to pass them around my application in your case something like:

```
public class ApiDataCriteria{

     public int? RowStatus {get;set;}
     public DateTime? Created {get;set;}
     public DateTime? Modified {get;set;}

}
```

Populate this according to your current search criteria (most likely based on user selection in the UI) then pass into the method I created above like this:

```
public IList<ApiData> SearchApiData(ApiDataCriteria criteria)
{

        ICriteria query = _session.CreateCriteria<ApiData>();

        if (criteria.rowStatus.HasValue)
        {
            query.Add(Restrictions.Eq("RowStatus", criteria.rowStatus.Value));
        }

        if (criteria.createdDate.HasValue)
        {
            query.Add(Restrictions.Eq("CreatedDate", criteria.createdDate.Value));
        }

        return query.List<ApiData>();

}
```

That way you only need a single method whose signature won't change even if you add more search criteria later on.